# Batch File: Deleting .File Extension Type Files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm working with an application that creates a generic file type extension for data log information. I'm trying to create a batch file script that would delete data log files that are 5 days or older. I don't have the most Batch File experience, but I have found the following script below works correctly for many file types, except for the generic .File type extension.

```
    forfiles /p "C:\SOAP_Data" /s /m *.* /d -5 /c "cmd /c del @path" & 
    forfiles /p "C:\HL7_Data" /s /m *.* /d -5 /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

Is there some tweak I can do to the script to make it include the deletion of the .File extension files as well? I've tried to add *.file to the folder path, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: `*.*` means "all files with any extension", so I doubt, it spares `*.FILE`

Comment: Does the following command show any .File files? `forfiles /p "." /s /m *.* /d -5 /c "cmd /c ECHO DEL @path"`.

Comment: Thanks @lit . It didn't show me any .File files with that command, but I did not know about the ECHO feature. It helped me troubleshoot to get to the solution.

Comment: @mevorahde - Since it did not show any `.File` files, that would seem to suggest that there are no `.File` files in the directory structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through troubleshooting using the ECHO of the delete path, I was able to find the following solution:

```
    forfiles /p "C:\SOAP_Data"  /d -5 /c "cmd /c  DEL @path" & 
    forfiles /p "C:\HL7_Data"  /d -5 /c "cmd /c  DEL @path"
```